# csv swap columns into rows javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv

I want to swap csv's columns into rows.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if array with values as following

```
   var matrix = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ];
```

Then

```
   var w = matrix.length;
   var h = matrix[0].length;
   var i, j, t = [];
   for(i=0; i<h; i++) {
         t[i] = [];
         for(j=0; j<w; j++) {
         t[i][j] = a[j][i];
      }
   }
```

t is your required array.